# why xdotool getactivewindow results in XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed?

Tags: x11, ubuntu-22.04, xdotool

Running `xdotool getactivewindow` in the terminal results in

```
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
```

But I am almost sure that it was working some time ago...

How to solve this issue?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and xdotool version 3.20160805.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an unknown reason, I was using wayland when this issue happened...

For another unknown reason, a reboot makes me switch back to X11, and then the issue is finally gone!